# PostGIS Shapefile Loader Tool / export manager

Tags: postgis, shapefile, import

I am trying to upload a shapefile to PostGIS using the PostGIS Shapefile Loader Tool/export manager and I receive this error?

Connection to the PostQL seems successful... though.

Any idea?

```
Connecting:  host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password='*********' client_encoding=UTF8
Connection succeeded.
Connecting:  host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password='*********' client_encoding=UTF8

==============================
Importing with configuration: sales_within_sydney_metro2prj, public, geom, C:\Temp\Sales_Final\Sales_Within_Sydney_Metro2Prj.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Point
PostGIS type: POINT[2]
Shapefile import failed.
Connecting:  host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password='*********' client_encoding=UTF8

==============================
Importing with configuration: sales_within_sydney_metro2prj, public, geom, C:\Temp\Sales_Final\Sales_Within_Sydney_Metro2Prj.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=0
Shapefile type: Point
PostGIS type: POINT[2]
Shapefile import failed.
```

Comment: is the postgis extension enabled in this database?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are trying to import into a database that is not PostGIS enabled.

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

try running this code if this fails then for sure it isn't enabled.

for enabling run:

```
CREATE extension postgis;
```